# Stop triggering GitHub Actions on updating some files in repository

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a repository that has a `README.md` file and has GitHub Actions enabled. Whenever I edit anything in the `README.md` file, the Action gets triggered.
I don't want my app to be rebuilt if I change only the `README.md`

How can I exclude some files from triggering Actions, just as we have `.gitignore` file to exclude some files from being committed and pushed.

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpaths.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Got it..Have answered the question too...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will do the work:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
    paths-ignore:
      - '**/README.md'
```

Comment: Surely if you change the workflow definition you _do_ want the new version to run?